# How to merge shapefiles of two countries with QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, merge

I want to merge the shapefile of Nigeria and Cameroon admin level 1. I downloaded the files from gadm but I cannot merge the files with QGIS or find a shapefile of Africa having countries at states level. Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: What is the exact problem? What do you do to merge them? Did you get any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply copy and paste the features from one layer to the other. The second one must be in edit mode for that. Just as you would do with a text editor.

Or take the whole world shapefile from Natural Earth, select the two and export the selection to another file.